# Pareto distribution with Gamma prior on parameter $\theta$

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, pareto-distribution

I want to calculate the posterior distribution of Pareto distribution with known parameter $X_m$ and unknown parameter $\theta$, with conjugate prior on $\theta$ the Gamma distribution:

My effort is the following :

$$f(y;\theta,X_m)=\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y^{\theta+1}}$$
\begin{align*}
    f(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n;\theta,X_m) &= \theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_1^{\theta+1}}\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_2^{\theta+1}},\dots,\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_n^{\theta+1}}  \\
    &= \theta^{n} X_m^{\theta n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
     &= \frac{\theta^{n} X_m^{\theta n}}{X_m} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
     &= \theta^{n} \left(\frac{1}{X_m}\right)^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m X_m^{\theta }}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
      &= \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m^{\theta +1}}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
        &= \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1}
\end{align*}

Now the prior distribution for $\theta$ is Gamma Distribution with $$\theta \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$$

and $f(\theta)$ is :

\begin{align*}
   f(\theta) &= \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta \theta}\\
    &\propto \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta \theta}
\end{align*}

Binding them together (likelihood $\times$ prior) we obtain the posterior distribution of parameter $\theta$ given the data:

$$f(\theta |y) \propto f(y|\theta)f(\theta)$$ which is :

\begin{align*}
f(\theta |y) &\propto f(y|\theta)f(\theta)\\
&\propto \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1}  \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta \theta}\\
&=\theta^{n} \theta^{\alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{-\beta \theta} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1} \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} \log\left[e^{-\beta \theta} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1}  \right]\\
&= \theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} \log \left(e^{-\beta \theta}\right )+\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1} \right)\\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} -\beta \theta +(\theta+1) \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} -\beta \theta +\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)  \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} -\theta \left[ \beta - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) \right] +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)  \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} -\theta \left[ \beta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right) \right] +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)  \\
&\propto \theta^{\underbrace{n + \alpha}_{}-1} -\theta \left[ \underbrace{\beta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right)} \right] 
\end{align*}

therefore we conclude that $$\theta | y \sim Gamma \left(n+\alpha,\beta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right) \right)$$

I do not know if I am completely right in my calculations.Can someone check me ?
I know I have omitted the boundaries $x<X_m$ and the likelihood should be:
$$\theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1} \mathbf{I}_{X_m < \min(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}$$ but i don't think that plays any important role here.I am correct ?

**Edit**

As @Jarle Tuflo has pointed out the log issue in the comments I edit the OP as:

\begin{align*}
f(\theta |y) &\propto f(y|\theta)f(\theta)\\
&\propto \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1}  \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta \theta}\\
&=\theta^{n} \theta^{\alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{-\beta \theta} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1} \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{-\beta \theta}e^{\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{X_m}{y_i})^{\theta+1}\right)}  \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{-\beta \theta + \log \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{X_m}{y_i})^{\theta+1}\right)}  \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{\left[ -\beta \theta +\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)\right]}   \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{\left[-\theta \left[ \beta - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) \right] +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) \right]}  \\
&=\theta^{n + \alpha-1}X_m^{-n} e^{\left[-\theta \left[ \beta +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right) \right] +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right) \right]}  \\
&\propto \theta^{\underbrace{n + \alpha}_{}-1} e^{\left[-\theta \left[ \underbrace{\beta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right)} \right] \right]}
\end{align*}

Comment: That $Gamma \left(n+\alpha,\beta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log  \left(\frac{y_i}{X_m}\right) \right)$ result is the same as [given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution).  The indicator function in the likelihood (perhaps with $\le$ rather than $\lt$) is desirable, if only because it would become  important if you did not know $X_m$; since you do know it here, you have other problems if any of the $y_i < X_m$

Comment: In your derivation of the posterior, the step where you suddenly take the log is clearly incorrect.  Instead, note that you have a number of factors all raised to power of $\theta$ so you should be able to rewrite that into something proportional to $e^{-\beta_1\theta}$ where $\beta_1$ is the shape of posterior gamma distribution.

Comment: @JarleTufto why I am not allowed to take the log?I had to keep the exp going?

Comment: @Henry therefore how this problem that you say might affect the posterior distribution?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson My point is that if you are told the minimum possible value is some fixed number and then shown data below that number then you cannot trust what you are told.

Comment: @Henry understood.Thank you.This is all I wanted.

Comment: @JarleTufto see the edit.Hope now is correct

Comment: Where are the indicators?

Comment: @Xi'an the indicators must be included?